# Executing php process using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created a server using php. I also created an html page that acts as the control panel for the php server. If I visit the control panel page and the php server is not running, I want to push on a button which creates a new separate process that launches the php server.

Here is the code that launches the php server (launchserver.php) using a terminal:
    #!/usr/bin/php -q

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    require_once 'lib/server.php';
    require_once 'lib/client.php';

    set_time_limit(0);

    // Get the local ip address of the host machine (NOTE: Not the loop back address)
    $command="/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'";
    $ipaddress = exec ($command);
    $server = new Server($ipaddress, 15000);
    $server->run();
?>
```

To run the server, I just open a terminal and execute "php -q launchserver.php".

However, I don't want to launch the php script using a terminal, I want to use my new control panel page, where I can click on a button and the button creates a separate process which executes the launchserver.php script and stands up the server and if I leave the control page, the server does not die because I'm no longer in the control page.

Comment: You won't be able to execute the PHP file, if the PHP server is not already running, and you certainly can't do any of those operations through JS or html.

Comment: But you need PHP to be running in order to run the PHP script..

Comment: If your server isn't running you won't be able to talk to it. You could, perhaps, do this if you can configure `xinetd` to do it, or you have Apache running and use a web page there to start your server. Mostly, server processes are started at boot time.

Comment: I do have apache2 httpd web server running with php. I just want to be able to stand up the php server from my control panel page by click on a button :(

Comment: Please explain "stand up". It's not a term I'm familiar with relating to PHP and Apache.

Comment: Mmm... Is there a way to tell apache to run my php script when it starts the web services?
@Mike W, how can I use xinetd to stand up my php server?

Comment: @seangates, I'm sorry, what I meant by "stand up" is launch or execute the php script which starts the server.

Comment: @DavidNA `xinetd` is a daemon process that runs on Linux boxes that starts server & protocol services on demand. I can't advise on how to configure it, and it's off-topic for [so]. If you want to explore that you could ask on [unix.se]

Comment: @MikeW Thank Mike, I will take a look at this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar recently (had to run some php code on another file using an HTML button).

This is my suggestion (I am a "junior", so there probably is a better/simpler solution):

Change your launchserver.php file to this:

```
<?php
if($_POST) {
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  require_once 'lib/server.php';
  require_once 'lib/client.php';

  set_time_limit(0);

  // Get the local ip address of the host machine (NOTE: Not the loop back address)
  $command="/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'";
  $ipaddress = exec ($command);
  $server = new Server($ipaddress, 15000);
  $server->run();
  }
?>
```

Then you need a button with "onclick".
e.g. 
     `<button onclick="startMyServer();">Start My Server</button>`

Then the JS function:

```
function startMyServer() {
  var startServer = 1;
  $.post("<full url here>/launchserver.php", { 'startServer': startServer }, function(d){

  });
}
```

This will act like you sent a form to the file. $.post requires JQuery, so be sure to include that.

So if you click the button it will send $_POST to your php file and if $_POST was sent, then the code in the php file runs.

I hope this is helpful. I used this JQuery function to run some php code ( mysql queries located on another file) and it works flawlessly for me.

Since you mentioned that "I do have apache2 httpd web server running with php", it should do the trick for you.

Comment: I will give your suggestion a try and will report back. Thank you!

Comment: hey I tried it, but it didn't work. It did launched the server and the server performed its executions, but then it just died :(